# Flex4 ButtonBar set icon doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex

```
<s:ButtonBar id="buttonBar"  width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="15" 
                 dataProvider="{buttonBarData}" change="buttonBar_changeHandler(event)"/>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:ArrayList id="buttonBarData">
        <fx:Object label="test" icon="{newIcon}" cmd="openfile"/>
        <fx:Object label="test" icon="{openIcon}" cmd="openfile" />
        <fx:Object label="test" icon="{saveIcon}" cmd="savefile"/>
        <fx:Object label="test" icon="{checkIcon}" cmd="check"/>
        <fx:Object label="test" icon="{undoIcon}" cmd="undo"/>
        <fx:Object label="test" icon="{redoIcon}" cmd="redo"/>
    </s:ArrayList>
</fx:Declarations>
```

But this can not work, the icons does not display, why this happen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention the iconfield property in the Buttonbar mxml tag as icon as follows:-

```
<s:ButtonBar id="buttonBar"  width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="15" 
             dataProvider="{buttonBarData}" change="buttonBar_changeHandler(event)" iconField="icon"/>
```

Then only it will recognize which field to take icon from.

Comment: Thank you for answer this question!! But flex4 buttonbar has not the attribute iconField. It does not work too after I set iconField.

Comment: I used your code for testing and it is working fine with iconField. Spark ButtonBar definately has iconField Property. Are you using embeded icon class or just icon path variable in the dataprovider? Wit embed icon class it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, I use embeded icon class. Now when I use mx buttonBar, the code work perfect. But when I use Spark ButtonBar like s:ButtonBar, the code doesn't work. I use Flex Builder for my editor, but it doesn't prompt iconField attribute.

Comment: Its working fine for me. As per the Adobe documentation iconField Property is there. Check out the following link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html#propertySummary .  In that link you can see the iconfield property in the public inherited properties.

Comment: I use Flex 4.1 for my project

Comment: Oh, after I try this by iconFiled, Flex builder show me an error during compilation phase. But I found the code work perfectly. Why would this happen?

Comment: May be some compiler setting issue. What error you were getting?

Comment: The flex builder prompt that "Not for the component type "spark.components.ButtonBar" parsing attribute 'iconField'", what configuration should I modify？

Comment: If it is showing as warning (Yellow Sign) then you can ignore it.

Comment: One more way of displaying icons in your buttonbar is by providing custom skin to your buttonbar. Following link will help you:- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/28/displaying-icons-in-a-spark-buttonbar-control-in-flex-4/